# Not getting any error output in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm unable to get any error output from my Flutter web app. Printing to the console using

```
print('some text');
```

works fine, but no errors get printed. For example, throwing an exception

```
throw new Exception('testexception');
```

doesn't result in any output, neither in the browser console nor in IntelliJ. The log level settings in Chrome are set to `[Info, Warnings, Errors]`.

I even tried implementing a custom error handler

```
void main(){
    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
        print('main.onError: details: ${details.toString()}');
    };

    runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

but no luck. Do I have to enable error outputs somewhere? I can't find any info about this in the documentation.

I tried running the app both using the `Dart Dev Server` (which is started when using `Run` from IntelliJ), as well as calling `webdev serve` and `webdev serve --auto restart` from the Terminal.

Answer (score 3):

[Flutter Web](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web) currently doesn't have a way to be debugged. Will generate a `main.dart.js` and you can debug it with Chrome console.

One cool trick to ***"debug"*** your Web App, is by showing a popup to your browser:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  js.context.callMethod("alert", <String>["Your debug message"]);
}
```

Comment: @Magnus wasn't trying to debug, he simply wanted exceptions to be printed in console like print.

Comment: This question is 4 years old and a lot has changes since then. You can now print without issues on Flutter Web. Be mindful when checking questions and dates.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look to see if it was a known issue?  Flutter-web is only at developer preview level. If there's not a current issue, create one, and provide a minimal "how to reproduce". I'm sure the Flutter-web team would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in both IDE and its correctly working in Intellij but not in VSCode. Its showing white blank screen give it try to run again `flutter run -d chrome` and wait in blank screen for 2minutes.

And check the SDK path of flutter in visual code is correct or not.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, the `console.log` method is used to output to the Web browser's JavaScript console.

So you can do it from Dart by getting the JavaScript *console* object and invoking that method on it.

```
import 'dart:js' as javascript; // ignore: avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter
```

```dart
/// Invoke the the JavaScript `console.log` method.

void logToBrowser(String message) {
  final console = javascript.context['console'] as javascript.JsObject;

  console.callMethod('log', [message]);
}
```

Since `dart:js` is only supported for Dart compiled to JavaScript, this means the Flutter app using it will only work as a Flutter Web app. Importing it will mean the code won't work for an app targeting iOS, Android, etc.

Tip: the JavaScript *console* object has other methods that can be invoked. Instead of `log`, use `info`, `warn` and `error`. Those last two highlight the entry when they appear in the console.

Comment: @Magnus already mentioned in his question that print outputs to console, he was just complaining that exceptions aren't.